# Portable and Tight Bit Packing

Tags: c, network-programming, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have three `unsigned ints`, {`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`}, which I want to pack with non-standard lengths, {9,5,7,11} respectively. I wish to make a network packet (`unsigned char pkt[4]`) that I can pack these values into and unpack them reliably on another machine using the same header file regardless of endianness.

Everything I have read about using packed structs suggests that the bit-ordering will not be predictable so that is out of the question. So that leaves me with bit-set and bit-clear operations, but I'm not confident in how to ensure that endianness will not cause me problems. Is the following sufficient, or shall I run into problems with the endianness of `a` and `d` separately?

```
void pack_pkt(uint16_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t c, uint16_t d, uint8_t *pkt){
    uint32_t pkt_h = ((uint32_t)a & 0x1FF)      // 9 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)b & 0x1F) << 9)  // 5 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)c & 0x3F) << 14) // 7 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)d & 0x7FF) << 21); //11 bits
    *pkt = htonl(pkt_h);
}

void unpack_pkt(uint16_t *a, uint8_t *b, uint8_t *c, uint16_t *d, uint8_t *pkt){
    uint32_t pkt_h = ntohl(*pkt);
    (*a) = pkt_h & 0x1FF;
    (*b) = (pkt_h >> 9) & 0x1F;
    (*c) = (pkt_h >> 14) & 0x3F;
    (*d) = (pkt_h >> 21) & 0x7FF;
}
```

If so, what other measures can I take to ensure portability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs with bitfields are indeed essentially useless for this purpose, as their field order and even padding rules are not consistent.

> shall I run into problems with the endianness of `a` and `d` separately?

The endianness of `a` and `d` doesn't matter, their byte-order is never used. `a` and `d` are not reinterpreted as raw bytes, only their integer values are used or assigned to, and in those cases endianness does not enter the picture.

There is an other problem though: `uint8_t *pkt` in combination with `*pkt = htonl(pkt_h);` means that *only the least significant byte is saved* (regardless of whether it is executed by a little endian or big endian machine, because this is not a reinterpretation, it's an implicit conversion). `uint8_t *pkt` is OK by itself, but then the resulting group of 4 bytes must be copied into the buffer it points to, it cannot be assigned all in one go. `uint32_t *pkt` would enable such a single-assignment to work without losing data, but that makes the function less convenient to use.

Similarly in `unpack_pkt`, only one byte of data is currently used.

When those issues are fixed, it should be good:

```
void pack_pkt(uint16_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t c, uint16_t d, uint8_t *buffer){
    uint32_t pkt_h = ((uint32_t)a & 0x1FF)      // 9 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)b & 0x1F) << 9)  // 5 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)c & 0x3F) << 14) // 7 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)d & 0x7FF) << 21); //11 bits
    uint32_t pkt = htonl(pkt_h);
    memcpy(buffer, &pkt, sizeof(uint32_t));
}

void unpack_pkt(uint16_t *a, uint8_t *b, uint8_t *c, uint16_t *d, uint8_t *buffer){
    uint32_t pkt;
    memcpy(&pkt, buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t pkt_h = ntohl(pkt);
    (*a) = pkt_h & 0x1FF;
    (*b) = (pkt_h >> 9) & 0x1F;
    (*c) = (pkt_h >> 14) & 0x3F;
    (*d) = (pkt_h >> 21) & 0x7FF;
}
```

An alternative that works without worrying about endianness at any point is manually deconstructing the `uint32_t` (rather than conditionally byte-swapping it with `htonl` and then reinterpreting it as raw bytes), for example:

```
void pack_pkt(uint16_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t c, uint16_t d, uint8_t *pkt){
    uint32_t pkt_h = ((uint32_t)a & 0x1FF)      // 9 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)b & 0x1F) << 9)  // 5 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)c & 0x3F) << 14) // 7 bits
                 | (((uint32_t)d & 0x7FF) << 21); //11 bits
    // example serializing the bytes in big endian order, regardless of host endianness
    pkt[0] = pkt_h >> 24;
    pkt[1] = pkt_h >> 16;
    pkt[2] = pkt_h >> 8;
    pkt[3] = pkt_h;
}
```

The original approach isn't bad, this is just an alternative, something to consider. Since nothing is ever reinterpreted, endianness does not matter at all, which may increase confidence in the correctness of the code. Of course as a downside, it requires more code to get the same thing done. By the way, even though manually deconstructing the `uint32_t` and storing 4 separate bytes looks like a lot of work, GCC can [compile it efficiently](https://godbolt.org/z/xKGdxe) into a `bswap` and 32bit store. On the other hand Clang misses this opportunity and other compilers may as well, so this is not without its drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your explanation and alternate method really helped me understand how it all works really well.

Answer (score 0):

for packing and packing i suggest use struct like this

- remember size of struct is different in other machines like 8 bit system vs 32 bit system compile same struct with different sizes we call it padding in struct so you can use pack to be sure struct size is same in transmitter and receiver

```c
typedef struct {
    uint8_t A;
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t C;
    uint8_t D;
} MyPacket;
```

now you can stream this struct into byte stream such as SerialPort or UART or something else
and in the receiver you can pack bytes to gether

see the following functions

```c
void transmitPacket(MyPacket* packet) {
    int len = sizeof(MyPacket);
    uint8_t* pData = (uint8_t*) packet;
    while (len-- > 0) {
        // send bytes 1 by 1
        transmitByte(*pData++);
    }
}

void receivePacket(MyPacket* packet) {
    int len = sizeof(MyPacket);
    uint8_t* pData = (uint8_t*) packet;
    while (len-- > 0) {
        // receive bytes 1 by 1
        *pData++ = receiveByte();
    }
}
```

remember bit ordering in byte is same every where but you must check your byte ordering for be sure packet will not be miss understand in receiver

for example if sizeof your packet is 4 bytes and you send low byte first
you have to receive low byte in receiver

in your code you get packet in uint8_t* pointer but your actual sizeof packet is uint32_t and is 4 bytes

Comment: Hi @ali, thanks for your input. This doesn't really address the issue of sending from a little-endian system to a big-endian system. My setup also includes a 32-bit computer on one end and a 64-bit computer on the other end.

Comment: if two end system use different endian system such as little-endian vs big-endian we have to use byte swap function, for reverse uint16_t or uint32_t variables but our uint8_t variables is same,
and remember bits variables always storing in a package like uint32_t

Comment: How can I be sure that the packing order of the packed struct is consistent on both devices? As far as I am aware the ordering is not defined in the standard and is therefor not portable. See the first answer in [this stack overflow post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203099/concept-of-bit-fields)

Comment: @MarcianoPreciado this answer doesn't use bitfields, so the order is defined - but it is also useless for your purpose because it doesn't address the use of unusually-sized fields